# Saving Visio .vsdx drawing into a format that preserves its fonts, pixels, etc

Tags: latex, vector-graphics, microsoft-visio-2013, eps, embedded-fonts

I have a drawing saved as .vsdx file (made in visio 2013). How do I convert it to the .eps format (or any vectorized format preserving its fonts, pixels etc.) to be used later as LaTeX figure?

- Why not use "Export" instead in Visio 2013?
  The 2013 Visio has Export bar, which seems it embeds and preserves everything, eliminating the need to convert to .eps or any other vector-graphic supporting format. Isn't that true? can't I just use this Export function and turn my drawing into *.pdf (preserving its pixel and font) to be later used in LaTeX?

[image: AN EASYIER WAY: Why not instead use "Export" in Visio 2013 onwards!]

Comment: @Hastur: So Visio 2013 does it all, without the difficulty of going through any third party software (this was not possible in earlier version of Visio). I suggest all you guys take advantage of it.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26484/whats-the-best-way-to-embed-visio-diagrams

Answer (score 1):

Visio -> Save As -> vectorized file format e.g. **.svg*, **.wmf*, **.emf* ...

Comment: I don't know how to work with .SVG later in LaTeX. How about .eps? I don't have it in my save as section!

Comment: Windows doesn't provide _.eps_. As a workaround you can - e.g. with IrfanView (http://www.irfanview.com/) - create a _.pdf_ out of the vector format and _.pdf_ can be used in LaTeX...

Comment: There are also opportunities which make you able to use the formats from above in latex, however they are much more complicated imho.

Comment: can't I use adobe products to get the same .pdf file preserving all?

Comment: You can try it, however I am not sure if the vector properties keep existing or whether it works in general but worth a try for sure. I have no Visio ready here and so I can't test it for myself at the moment.

Comment: In Latex you can add packages to your file and import and use different formats `svg` included. After it will be a question if you are bounded to use or not that specific package by the eventual editor... but usually there are no problem.  __Warning__ Seldom `pdf` and `eps` images created under Windows presented problems with automatic submission of paper, just because there where the preview inside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test with some attempts, but start saving it in vectorial form.

After you can use any program to change your format in `eps` as for example [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) or convert from [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Note that with Latex you can add some packages and import directly images with different formats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
....
```

See for [example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package).